# Glassfish 4.1 and MariaDB troubles

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans, glassfish, mariadb, glassfish-4.1

I'm developing an enterprise application using Netbeans 8.2, Glassfish 4.1 and MariaDB, all of this on Ubuntu 18.04.

However, after all the connections with the DB are established, Glassfish returns this exception:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'OPTION'
```

As I've seen, the `SET OPTION` command was deprecated in MySQL 5.1 and finally removed in MySQL 5.6. MariaDB did the same in their 10.0 version. It seems that Glassfish 4.1 still uses this command.

That leads me to two main solutions:

- Upgrading Glassfish: Glassfish 4.1.1 is very unstable and it doesn't work most of the time. New versions (5.0.x) aren't compatible with Netbeans 8.2.
- Downgrading MariaDB: MariaDB 5.5 isn't available in Ubuntu 18.04 (in their website appears to be 14.04 as its last official version).
- Downgrading Ubuntu: I can downgrade my OS to 14.04, but I hope that could be my last option.

Can someone give me some advice on this? Thanks!

Comment: Regarding your first point: do you know [Payara](https://www.payara.fish/)? It's an enhanced version of GF that works very well. They stopped 4.x line development but the version is still downloadable. I don't use MySQL, so I have no idea whether the issue you mention was solved, but in my opinion it's definitely worth a try as the server, whilst being a Glassfish, is much better than the original GF.

Comment: Thanks friend, that made it. If you want to make an answer using this comment, I will mark it as accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [end of the period where Oracle offered a commercially-supported version of Glassfish, thus reducing it to a pure reference implementation role](https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/java-ee-and-glassfish-server-roadmap-update) in our experience marked a notable decline in usability and stability of Glassfish, which is a shame.  [Payara](https://www.payara.fish/) is an externally maintained and up to date version based on the Glassfish sources but with many improvements. Although they already stopped the evolution of GF4 for non-paying customers, they still do [offer a downloadable version](https://www.payara.fish/previous_releases). I encourage you to test it, if you like Glassfish you will love Payara :)

Answer (score 2):

The correct thing to do would be to use a version of the software that supports modern SQL syntax. Even if this is not the easiest solution, it most likely will pay off in the future.

---

Another way to solve this is to have [MariaDB MaxScale](https://mariadb.com/products/technology/maxscale) sit between your application and the database and configure it to translate the `SET OPTION` SQL to the correct `SET` form. This can be done with the [Regex filter](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-enterprise/mariadb-maxscale-22-regex-filter/) that is meant for situations just like this.

Here's a MaxScale configuration for a small SQL transformation service translates `SET OPTION` to `SET`:

```
[maxscale]
threads=auto

[my-database]
type=server
address=hostname-of-my-server
port=3306
protocol=MariaDBBackend

[database-monitor]
type=monitor
module=mariadbmon
servers=my-database
user=<username used to monitor the server>
passwd=<password for the user>
monitor_interval=5000

[replace-option]
type=filter
module=regexfilter
match=SET OPTION
replace=SET

[routing-service]
type=service
router=readconnroute
servers=my-database
user=<username used to monitor the server>
passwd=<password for the user>
filters=replace-option

[routing-listener]
type=listener
service=routing-service
protocol=MariaDBClient
port=3306
```